# Firebase Storage and Cloud Functions for Firebase error

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-storage, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

When you delete a file (specifically in this case photos) through Firebase Cloud Functions, some files are deleted well, some remain in Firebase Storage. I get an error in the logs when the files are not deleted, the text of the error.

```
Error: read ECONNRESET at exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11) at TCP.onread (net.js:569:26)
 Error: read ECONNRESET
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:569:26)
```

My code

```
  var functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage')();
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


// deleting functions 
exports.userDidDeleted = functions.auth.user().onDelete(event => {
    const user = event.data; // The Firebase user.

    const email = user.email; // The email of the user.
    const displayName = user.displayName; // The display name of the user.
    const userSearchLocationModelPath = '/userSearchLocationModel/' + user.uid;
     console.log('userDidDeleted', userSearchLocationModelPath);
    admin.database().ref(userSearchLocationModelPath).remove();

    // cards

    var cardsRef = admin.database().ref('cards')    
    cardsRef.orderByChild('ownerID').equalTo(user.uid).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
        console.log('cardsRef', snapshot.key, snapshot.val); 
        const cardRef = '/cards/' + snapshot.key;      
        admin.database().ref(cardRef).remove();
        // location
        admin.database().ref('cardLocation').child(snapshot.key).remove();

        // photo 

          const filePath = 'cardImages/' + snapshot.key + '/mainCardPhoto/' + 'main.jpg';
        const bucket = gcs.bucket('example-example7.appspot.com');
        const file = bucket.file(filePath);
        const pr = file.delete();

    });

});
```

Comment: ECONNRESET means you are not returning the promise. By returning your promise, the function waits to clean up until all of the work is done. Here are a couple things to check out to find out more: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NgZIb6Uwpjc&spfreload=5

Comment: @JenPerson thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After consulting Jen Person I changed the code and it works for me.

// deleting functions

```
exports.userDidDeleted = functions.auth.user().onDelete(event => {
    const user = event.data; // The Firebase user.

    const email = user.email; // The email of the user.
    const displayName = user.displayName; // The display name of the user.
    const userSearchLocationModelPath = '/userSearchLocationModel/' + user.uid;
     console.log('userDidDeleted', userSearchLocationModelPath);
    admin.database().ref(userSearchLocationModelPath).remove();

    // cards

    var cardsRef = admin.database().ref('cards')    
    cardsRef.orderByChild('ownerID').equalTo(user.uid).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
        // there, I queried!
             console.log('cardsRef', snapshot.key, snapshot.val); 
        const cardRef = '/cards/' + snapshot.key;      
        admin.database().ref(cardRef).remove();
        // location
        admin.database().ref('cardLocation').child(snapshot.key).remove();

        // photo 
        const firebasestoragePath = 'firebasestorage.googleapis.com';

        const placeVenuePhotoPath = '' + snapshot.child('photoURLsProperties').child('placeVenuePhoto').val(); 

        if (placeVenuePhotoPath.includes(firebasestoragePath)) {
          const filePath = 'cardImages/' + snapshot.key + '/mainCardPhoto/' + 'main.jpg';
          const bucket = gcs.bucket('example-example7.appspot.com');
         const file = bucket.file(filePath);
          const pr = file.delete();
          return console.log(filePath, "is deleted");
        } else {
          return console.log("card did not have a custom image", snapshot.key);
        }          
      });
```